# [hibernate:2.1.1]: No bean named 'transactionManagerwordpressSessionFactory' is defined

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-2.0

```
I have upgraded grails from 1.3.7 to 2.1.1, and after starting server (grails run-app) following error is being thrown. I'm not getting the solution-
```

1st exception-

```
| Error 2012-09-17 14:23:09,767 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [hibernate:2.1.1]: No bean named 'transactionManagerwordpressSessionFactory' is defined
Message: No bean named 'transactionManagerwordpressSessionFactory' is defined
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

2nd Error-

```
| Error 2012-09-17 14:23:09,959 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [taxonomy:1.2]: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  108 | methodMissing in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     14 | init          in com.grailsrocks.taxonomy.TaxonomyService
|     43 | doCall . . .  in TaxonomyGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|    334 | innerRun      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run           in java.lang.Thread
```

3rd error-

```
| Error 2012-09-17 14:23:11,762 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  108 | methodMissing                    in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     17 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
|    301 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    294 | executeForEnvironment            in     ''
|    270 | executeForCurrentEnvironment . . in     ''
|    334 | innerRun                         in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
```

The above error is being thrown, and server is not starting up. I am using grails 2.1.1 with jdk1.6. Kindly help me for the same.
.

Thank You in advance